# Lightning Aura CORS Blocked using JSZip library

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, cors

I have files on a sharepoint server which I want my lightning aura component to get and download for me. I am using JSZip to zip the files together.

As my download function requests the files from the web URL of the files from sharepoint, I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at [Sharepoint URL] from origin 'https://nec--testing.lightning.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Is the error being given by the sharepoint server or by lightning? If by sharepoint, is my only option to somehow make those web URLs have a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header? (is that even possible?) If by lightning, what should I do?

I would appreciate any explanation on what is going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error caused by SharePoint not allowing access (Access-Control-Allow-Origin), the error is provided by the web browser. This can't be fixed from the Lightning side of things.

I won't provide any specific links, as I can't seem to find a reliable (e.g. official Microsoft documentation) on the matter, but it seems you might be able to convince SharePoint to add the right headers; I'd recommend that you do your own research, contact their Support, and/or ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) for a better chance of solving the problem.

However, if the files are small (<3MB or so), you could potentially write some Apex code to call the SharePoint server, or if that doesn't work, you could also potentially spin up a Heroku app or other type of server you can control to act as a proxy. Servers aren't bound by CORS and can therefore do whatever connections they want. There's likely a viable solution lurking out there, but it's either not straight-forward, or not well-documented.